# Android Studio.Debugging does not work

Tags: debugging, android-studio

I need to debug my app, but **debugging does not work**.There is a message in event log:

```
     System Health
     This IDE is running on a Java JRE instead of a full Java JDK.
     This does not work; debugging (among other features) will not work.
     You must configure the boot JDK (via Help > Find Action... > Switch
```

My JDK home path in Android Studio is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`.
I have `JAVA_HOME` variable: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111`.I tried to change `JAVA_HOME` variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`,but Android Studio did not start.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same message with Android Studio 2.3.2.
I had installed Java SDK 7, and then accepted an update to Java 8.
After much ado following advises about setting environment variables JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, STUDIO_JDK and PATH in dozens of different combinations, I finally found out what at least my problem was and it's very simple indeed.

Turns out, the update to Java 8 was only for the JRE so the SDK was still 7, and Studio 2.3.2 requires JDK 8. So after installing that, not one single environment variable was necessary to get rid of the "This IDE is running on a Java JRE instead of" message.

Hope this helps.

/z